# R list object size larger than corresponding raw data file

Tags: r, list, csv, dataframe, import

I've got a CSV file I import into R and then split into several subsets which consitute my list "importedData":

```
filePath <- "Test.csv"
rowsPerBatch <- 58

numRows <- length(count.fields(file = filePath, sep = ","))
readSegment <- function(x) fread(file = filePath, sep = ",", header = TRUE, skip = rowsPerBatch*(x-1), nrows = rowsPerBatch-1)
importedData <- lapply(1:(numRows/rowsPerBatch), readSegment)
```

The raw CSV file is just 4MB. However, the list object within R is 17.8 MB large. Why is that the case? Is there a way to do the above more memory-efficiently?

I am planning on scaling-up the algoirithm above to handle several dozen CSV files each >200MB. If each of their corresponding list objects in R is 3x their original size, I'm afraid the memory usage will get out of control very quickly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the *Advanced R* book's section on [memory usage](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html), numeric vectors occupy 8 bytes per element, integer vectors occupy 4 bytes per element, and complex vectors occupy 16 bytes per element.

Therefore, depending on the number of rows and columns in the input CSV file, the resulting R object can be significantly larger than the input CSV file.

Based on the amount of RAM available on the machine being used to process the data, R users rely on the following strategies to deal with limited memory, including:

- sampling: analyze a random sample of the input data,
- subsetting: process the data in subsets, then combine results, and
- aggregating: aggregate data to higher unit of analysis, then analyze it.

Since R loads all objects into memory in order to process them, one must not only have enough RAM to load an object, but also enough RAM to process the object, including writing additional output objects.

Please note that storage formats such as `data.table` and `tibble` are more efficient than the Base R `data.frame`, and can save as much as 50% in RAM usage as I illustrate in [American Community Survey Example](https://github.com/lgreski/acsexample).